# How to Center Horizontally a Grid Item in a 2 Column Grid?

Tags: css, grid

I have a grid container with 2 items in each row. The last row has only 1 item and I want it to be centered horizontally and still be as wide as all the other items. Right now, the last item is on the left.

I have tried `justify-self: center;` on the last item, but it doesn't work.

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap: 40px;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #38bdf8;
  border-radius: 16px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want it to be centered horizontally and still be as wide as all the other items.

When it comes to CSS grid, you can't just center something, it has to follow the grid. You defined two columns, and so there's no middle column for the last element to occupy.

To achieve this using CSS grid, we need to add more columns.

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  column-gap: 40px;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #38bdf8;
  border-radius: 16px;
  height: 50px;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item:last-child {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

almost there... just add span on last item

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap: 40px;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #38bdf8;
  border-radius: 16px;
  height: 50px;
}

.item:last-child {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I said in my question, all the items should have the same width.

Answer (score 0):

if you want all items same width, and based on your actual css with container 700px and column-gap 40px, you can modify the last-child css as follow:

```css
        .item:last-child {
            grid-column: auto / span 2;
            width: 330px;
            justify-self: center;
        }
```

here we give a real width at the last item equal to others

we keep the span 2 but we justify center this last item